# Drawing polyline in realtime

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift2, apple-maps

I'm fairly new to ios and I would like to know what would be the best approach to draw polyline on google map while user is on the move. So it would only show the path the user has traveled. I'm thinking about using current location as the destination and redraw the polyline as user moves.

EDIT : I'm not even sure if google map is the way to go for this particular scenario since this app is free and there will be fee for API call over 2500 times/day. Is it better to go with Apple Map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [these guidelines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#add_a_polyline):

You need to create a `GMSMutablePath` and add the current user location. As the user moves you add more coordinates to the `GMSMutablePath`.

When you need to draw the line just instantiate a new `GMSPolyline` object and set the map property of the `GMSPolyline` removing the previously drawn polyline setting it's map property to `nil`.

Comment: I guess that would require a lot of API call even for a short trip since I need to get the current location consistently and would run over API usage limit in no time. Would it be better to use apple map instead?

Comment: This API calls doesn't count on usage limits according to https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details